# When I write this snippet in my asp.net Razor C# I was getting Index was outside the bounds of the array from the following code

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

When call the code below.  I get a index was outside the bounds of the array.  Doesn't the split function return an array?

```
@{

     Array userData = File.ReadAllLines(dataFile);
     foreach(string line in userData){
           char [] c = new char[]{'^'};
           string[] x = line.Split(c) ;
            {<p>@x[1] </p>}
     }
}
```

Comment: Your `string[] x = line.Split(c);` is not returning an array with at least two elements in it.

Comment: @Habib This should be an answer, not a comment. It's actually THE answer

Answer (score 0):

You just need to check that `x.Lenght > 1`
What you're getting there is probably `line.Split(c)` returns an array with just 1 element in it and therefore you're getting index out of bounds error when trying to access 2nd element.